# Timeout exceeded during the transaction confirmation process. Be aware the transaction could still get confirmed

Tags: contract-deployment, dapp-development, ethereumjs

contract deploy , web3 version is 1.0.0-beta.52.

```
let {bytecode, interface} = require('./1-compile')

let Web3 = require('web3')

let web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:7545')

console.log('version :', web3.version)

const account = '0xdf9c60D4F6E92c977f220dc507eDAfaEDF026c1c'

let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))

contract.deploy({
    data: '0x'+bytecode, 
    arguments: ['hello world'] 
}).send({
    from: account,
    gas : '500000',
    gasPrice: '1',
}).then((instance) => {
    console.log('address: ', instance.options.address)
}).catch(err =>{
    console.log('err : ', err)
})
```

when i execute `node xx.js`, console outputs text like this. How can I fix it.

```
version : 1.0.0-beta.52
err :  { error:
   Error: Timeout exceeded during the transaction confirmation process. Be aware the transaction could still get confirmed!
       at _callee2$ (/Users/xx/Desktop/blockchain/workspace/my-dapp/node_modules/web3-core-method/dist/web3-core-method.cjs.js:418:36)
       at tryCatch (/Users/xx/Desktop/blockchain/workspace/my-dapp/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)
       at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/xx/Desktop/blockchain/workspace/my-dapp/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:271:22)
       at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/xx/Desktop/blockchain/workspace/my-dapp/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:97:21)
       at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/xx/Desktop/blockchain/workspace/my-dapp/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
       at _next (/Users/xx/Desktop/blockchain/workspace/my-dapp/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7),
  receipt:
   { transactionHash:
      '0xcb9122b4897ec6714938b475c47e6a5fc9d71bdc3efb850251285bcbc27dcf95',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash:
      '0xeaa09735ef6226fc103b64d82d13d48dac60f3d927f9b9941ac151ebe8e12afa',
     blockNumber: 1,
     from: '0xdf9c60d4f6e92c977f220dc507edafaedf026c1c',
     to: null,
     gasUsed: 267772,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 267772,
     contractAddress: '0x1c6B7774F8c77daad698B764b853cBfEDBa54fcd',
     logs: [],
     status: true,
     logsBloom:
      '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
     v: '0x1c',
     r:
      '0x696a6859397be535077e9848e5d8aef6116d907f56d4d21e36160e4b639ac9ff',
     s:
      '0x333862057233193fe9ba3da9ce63b2f77203f07ecc832b50e3222092622caca5' },
  confirmations: 1,
  confirmationChecks: 750 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/70253/53458
i find answer in this url. 
I copy the code

```
const OPTIONS = {
    defaultBlock :"latest",
    transactionConfirmationBlocks: 1,
    transactionBlockTimeout: 5
}

let Web3 = require('web3')

let web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:7545', null, OPTIONS)
```